# UIScrollView hiding UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have an a UIControlView with the following hierarchy.

```
...
UIView
  UIScrollview
    textfield
    button
    textfield
    button
NavigationBar
...
```

When this view loads the scrollview pushes the navigationBar off the screen or hides it?  What am I doing wrong?

When I drag a srollview onto the UIViewController storyboard, should the scrollview be at 480 or around 430 so its below the navigationbar?

// === HERE IS THE CODE (there is no other custom code besides this) ======

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
DLog(@"%f", self.scrollView.contentOffset.y);
//self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.view.contentOffset.x,0);

self.codeTextField.delegate = self;

self.mobileTextField.delegate = self;

[self.navBarLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor statDarkGray] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.navBarLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor statDarkGray] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self.navBarLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor statLightGray] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Light" size:17];
[self.navBarLabel.titleLabel setFont:font];


//SETUP TEXTFIELDS
// --- Setup textfield designs ---------
self.codeTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;

UIImage *fieldBGImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"code_textfield.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:20];
[self.codeTextField setBackground:fieldBGImage];
// for left padding
self.codeTextField.leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 88, 20)];
self.codeTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

self.mobileTextField.leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 88, 20)];
self.mobileTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;


// setup submit button

self.submitButton.titleLabel.text = @"Submit";
self.submitButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Light" size:18];
self.submitButton.enabled = NO;

[self.submitButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebutton_disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[self.submitButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebutton_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.submitButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebutton_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];


// setup submit button

self.resendCodeButton.enabled = NO;
self.resendCodeButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Light" size:18];

[self.resendCodeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redbutton_disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[self.resendCodeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redbutton_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.resendCodeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redbutton_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];


// SETUP BUTTONS
// The next arrow button
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cancel_normal.png"];
UIImage *backgroundSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cancel_selected.png"];
self.cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //adding action
[self.cancelButton setBackgroundImage:background forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.cancelButton setBackgroundImage:backgroundSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,0,background.size.width, background.size.height);
self.cancelButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.cancelButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.cancelButtonItem;

}
```

Comment: Show your code or bring more details.

Comment: Did you try reordering views and putting NavigationBar above other views?

Comment: You can't reorder the navigationbar in xcode 5 ios7, it won't let you drag them. See hierarchy above.

Answer (score 0):

The view was shown modally not pushed. And even though I designed a navbar and set one in the settings (translucent bar). It wasn't showing one?

So on the segue I was using show modally and the, no matter if it had a UIView or UIScrollView, never would show the navbar. By switching to a PUSH segue, it now shows the navbar. Fixed.

I just decided to push the view instead of modal to be done with it.

Comment: if this is the solution to your problem, can you be a bit more specific about what you did (for any future readers) then mark this as the answer?